# How can I use these different variables to get the total calories consumed by a person?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to find the total calories consumed by an individual if they eat certain things, for instance, this would be a sample input for a meal

```
meal = ["T-Bone", "T-Bone", "Green Salad1"]
```

Using data from the meal, we would get the required ingredients for each of the following items in the `meal: list`. This would be provided in another input string `recipes` like this...

```
recipes = ["Pork Stew: Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
"Green Salad1: Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
"T-Bone: Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"]
```

**the (*) displayed after each ingredient specifies how many of the same ingredients are required...**

for instance in `Pork Stew: Cabbage * 5 means 5 cabbages and Carrot times 1 means 1 carrot`
and from each of these ingredients, we would find out how many calories each ingredient contains by using the third and final input `db: str` like this

```
db = ["Cabbage:4,2,0", "Carrot:9,1,5", "Fatty Pork:431,1,5",
"Pineapple:7,1,0", "Steak Meat:5,20,10", "Rabbit Meat:7,2,20"]
```

1. Every 1st number in each ingredient determines the calories of fat, and they are multiplied by 5
2. Every second number in each ingredient determines the calories of protein, and they're also multiplied by 5
3. Every third number in each ingredient determines the total carbs, and they are multiplied by 9

So for instance (Cabbage: 4,2,0 translates to (4 cals of fat, 2 cals of protein and 0 cals of carbs) so the total calories of Cabbage should be (4 * 5)+(2 * 5)+(0*9) which is 30

Together, I must somehow use these three inputs and input them into a function `mealCal(meal: list[str], recipes: list[str], db: list[str])` and I expect the output to return the total number of calories consumed by the individual.

So far I have only figured out the total carbs, aka `db` and here is my code...

```
def contra(inputlst):
    g = []
    for x in inputlst:
        g.append(str.split(x,":"))
    return g
def split(inputlst):
    r = []
    for x in contra(inputlst):
        r.append((str.split(x[-1],",")))
    return r
def calories(inputlst):
    f = []
    for x in split(inputlst):
        s = int(x[0])*5
        g = int(x[1])*5
        h = int(x[2])*9
        f.append(s+g+h)
```

Now I'll have to somehow use this data to find the total calories present in the recipes, which are the result of what the input `meal` is gonna be.

Can someone please explain how can I do this... **Also please try to use the simplest code possible since I'm a beginner and I'm kinda confused from this question**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MapReduce principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). With the map part (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) you extract the calories from each line. And with the reduce part (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) you compute the sum of all the recipes.

You may need two map functions, one to extract the three numeric information and the other map to extract the calories from the three numbers.

```
def extract_values(field):
   return field.split(":")[1]

def extract_calories(field):
   return field.split(",")[0]
```

The reduce function will just be a sum of all the results from the previous map.

```
result = map(extract_values, db)
result = map(extract_calories, result)
result = reduce(sum, result)
```